# Computational speed of a complex Hierarchical GAM

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I have a large dataset (3.5+ million observations) of a binary response variable that I am trying to compute a Hierarchical GAM with a global smoother with individual effects that have a Shared penalty (e.g. 'GS' in [Pedersen et al. 2019](https://peerj.com/articles/6876/)). Specifically I am trying to estimate the following structure: Global > Geographic Zone (N=2) > Bioregion (N=20) > Season (N varies by bioregion). In total, I am trying to estimate 36 different nested parameters.

Here is the the code I am currently using:

```
modGS <- bam(
  outbreak ~ 
    te(days_diff,NDVI_mean,bs=c("tp","tp"),k=c(5,5)) + 
    t2(days_diff, NDVI_mean, Zone, Bioregion, Season, bs=c("tp", "tp","re","re","re"),k=c(5, 5), m=2, full=TRUE) +
    s(Latitude,Longitude,k=50), 
  family=binomial(),select = TRUE,data=dat)
```

My main issue is that it is taking a long time (5+ days) to construct the model. This nesting structure cannot be discretized, so I cannot compute it in parallel. Further I have tried `gamm4` but I ran into memory limit issues. Here is the gamm4 code:

```
modGS <- gamm4(
  outbreak ~ 
    t2(days_diff,NDVI_mean,bs=c("tp","tp"),k=c(5,5)) + 
    t2(days_diff, NDVI_mean, Zone, Bioregion, Season, bs=c("tp", "tp","re","re","re"),k=c(5, 5), m=2, full=TRUE) +
    s(Latitude,Longitude,k=50), 
  family=binomial(),select = TRUE,data=dat)
```

What is the best/most computationally feasible way to run this model?

Comment: Not familiar with gam syntax. What does `t2({5 variables}, ...)` mean? All 2-way combinations?

Comment: It is a way to generate tensor products that separates each penalty into penalized and unpenalized components. It creates new basis functions and penalties for all pair-wise combinations of penalized and unpenalized components between all pairs of marginal bases. edit: taken largely from the Pedersen et al. paper mentioned above

Comment: It should create a random surface of f(`days_diff`, `NDVI_mean`) for the interaction of the  other three variables. `t2(x, f, bs = c('tp'cr'), full = TRUE)` is the equivalent of `s(x, f, bs = 'fs')`

Answer (score 0):

I cut down the computational time by reducing the amount of bioregion levels and randomly sampling ca. 60% of the data. This actually allow me to calculate OOB error for the model.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an article I read recently](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095447017301377) that has a specific section on decreasing computational time. The main things they highlight are:

1. Use the `bam` function with it's useful fREML estimation, which refactorizes the model matrix to make calculation faster. Here it seems you have already done that.
2. Adding the `discrete = TRUE` argument, which assumes only a smaller finite number of unique values for estimation.
3. Manipulating `nthreads` in this function so it runs more than one core in parallel in your computer.

As the authors caution, the second option can reduce the amount of accuracy in your estimates. I fit some large models recently doing this and found that it was not always the same as the default `bam` function, so its best to use this as a quick inspection rather than the full result you are looking for.